# Add UILabel below the thumb of UISlider

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have created a table view and have added UISlider on each table view cell but i want to add UILabel (for show percentage) on thumb image (Down side).
Please give me example for showing percentage.
Like below image :

[image]

Comment: Check here [Sliders](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=slider),. you will find plenty of them.